# How can I replace e.g. *<anytext>* by \emph{anytext} using a regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I replace e.g.

```
*<anytext>*
```

by

```
\emph{anytext}
```

using a regex?

I've read at least 6 different general explanations, 4 of them on stackoverflow, of capture groups, but keep on doing something wrong.

I came up with

```
Find what:      \*(?:.*?)\*
Replace with:   \emph{\1}
```

but it replaces

```
*blablah*
```

by

```
\emph{}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - the only thing you are missing is a capturing group.

The `(?: ... )` construct makes your group non-capturing, which leads to inability to reference this group using `\1` expression. In order to fix this, remove `?:` to make it a "plain" capturing group:

```
Find what:      \*(.*?)\*
Replace with:   \emph{\1}
```

**Note 1:** A better approach to matching characters up to a special marker character is to use `[^*]*` in place of `.*?`. This helps you avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) in more complex expressions.

```
Find what:      \*([^*]*)\*
```

**Note 2:** I think Notepad++ uses `$` instead of `\` for group reference:

```
Replace with:   \emph{$1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Find: \*(.*?)\*
Replace: \\empth{$1}
```

Not sure you need to escape the `\` (in `\\empth`) in Notepad++.

`?:` means the content of the parentheses won't be captured, so you won't be able to use it in the replace expression afterwards. You need to remove it.